# Trigger Test Class code coverage not increase over 29

Tags: unit-test, code

**I have written the trigger below**

```
trigger CreditrequestTrigger on Credit_Request__c (after update) {

String body = '';
String subject = '';

List<User> Userlist = new List<User>([SELECT Name, Email FROM User WHERE User_License__c = 'Salesforce' AND IsActive = True]);

//system.debug(Userlist);
Map<String, String> Usermap= new Map<String, String>();
for(User Usersingle :Userlist)
{
 Usermap.put((String)Usersingle.get('Name'),(String)Usersingle.get('Email'));
}

OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id, DisplayName from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'support@sizmek.com'];

for(Credit_Request__c cr : trigger.new){   

  if( 'Complete' == cr.Status__c ){  

        subject = 'Credit Request Complete For Invoice # ' +cr.Invoice_Number__c;
        body = '<div style="width: 100%;text-align:center;"> 
        </div>\n\n';

        body += 'Hi ,\n\n';
        body += 'Invoice Number: ' + cr.Invoice_Number__c + '\n';
        body += 'Type: ' + cr.Type__c + '\n';

        Datetime InvoiceDate = cr.Invoice_Date__c;
        body += 'Invoice Date: ' + InvoiceDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy') + '\n';
        body += 'Invoice Amount: ' + cr.Invoice_Amount__c;

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String ToAddress=cr.Account_Sales_Rep__c;
         if(String.isNotBlank(ToAddress))
         {
            List<String> ToAddresssplit = ToAddress.split(';');
            List<String> ToAddresses=new List<String>();
            for(String SingleTo : ToAddresssplit)
            {
                if(String.isNotBlank((String)Usermap.get(SingleTo)))
                {
                ToAddresses.add((String)Usermap.get(SingleTo));
                }
            }                                   
            email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea.get(0).Id); 
            email.setSubject(subject);
            email.setPlainTextBody(body);
            email.setHTMLBody(body.replace('\n', '<BR>')+'<BR><BR>');
            email.setToAddresses(ToAddresses);
            if(ToAddresses.size()>0)
            {
            Messaging.sendEmail(new messaging.singleemailmessage[]{email});
            }
          }
        }        
    }
}
```

**And test class**

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
private class CreditrequestTrigger_Test {

    public static testMethod void test_trigger(){

    Test.startTest();  


    Credit_Request__c cr = [select id,Status__c from Credit_Request__c LIMIT 1];
    cr.Status__c = 'Completed';
    cr.Invoice_Number__c = '21224269';
    cr.Invoice_Amount__c = 94.10;
    cr.Type__c ='Credit';
    cr.Account_Sales_Rep__c = 'Suhas Rathod;Vaibhav Magdum';
    update cr;

    Map<String, String> Usermap= new Map<String, String>();     
    Usermap.put('Suhas Rathod','suhas@test.com');
    Usermap.put('Vaibhav Magdum','vaibhav@test.com');

    List<String> ToAddresses=new List<String>{'vaibhav.magdum@synechron.com'};                
    String subject = 'Credit Request Complete For Invoice # 1';

    String  body = '<div style="width: 100%;text-align:center;"> <img src="http://www.sizmek.com/Sizmek.png" /> </div>\n\n';
        body += 'Hi ,\n\n';
        body += 'Invoice Number: ' + cr.Invoice_Number__c + '\n';
        body += 'Type: ' + cr.Type__c + '\n';

        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setPlainTextBody(body);
        email.setHTMLBody(body.replace('\n', '<BR>')+'<BR><BR>');
        email.setOrgWideEmailAddressId('0D2C0000000L0RYKA0');
        email.setToAddresses(ToAddresses);
        Messaging.sendEmail(new messaging.singleemailmessage[]{email});
        System.assertEquals(cr.Status__c,'Completed');
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

But Trigger Test Class code coverage not increase over 29 try all can some one help to increase it @ Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change this line -

```
cr.Status__c = 'Completed';
```

to

```
cr.Status__c = 'Complete';
```